# Simple Nested Evaluations in DrRacket

Tags: lisp, scheme, racket, r5rs

so I'm working on some practice problems for my programming languages class, and one of the assignments is to create a script "MyEval" which allows you to do simple nested addition and multiplication. 
So for example the program would be able to do this `(MyEval '(1 +(3 *4)))` or deeper, but without having to do subtraction or more than 2 numbers and an operator. So not so complicated. However my mind is fried and I would love some guidance.
This is what I have so far

```
#lang racket
(define ns (make-base-namespace))
(define (MyEval lis)
  (cond
    [(and ; neither is a list and can be evaluated
     (not(list? (car lis)))
     (not(list? (caddr lis)))
       )
    (eval (cons (cadr lis) (list (car lis) (caddr lis)) ) ns)]

    [(list? (car lis))
     (MyEval (car lis))]

    [(list? (caddr lis))
     (MyEval (caddr lis))]      

   ) ;end of cond
 ) ;end of define
```

but as you guys might notice this would only solve the last inner parentheses , so if I do `(MyEval '(1 + (1 + 2)))` I get 3, not 4.
Any guidance or tip is appreciated, I don't know how accurate my title is, but if it isn't appropriate please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: Note: do **not** use the underlying `eval` of your environment.  If you do so, you're misunderstanding the assignment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually a good plan is to write some unit tests first. Examples of what the function should return for certain outputs. Try to think of boundary or corner cases, too. For instance:

```
(require rackunit)
(check-equal? (my-eval '(1 + (3 * 4)))
              13)
(check-equal? (my-eval '(20 + 20))
              40)
(check-equal? (my-eval 1) 
              1)
```

Of course these will all fail initially. But your goal is to get them to pass.

Next, you don't need to use `eval`, and shouldn't. You almost never want to use `eval` in real life. (Plus, isn't the whole point of your exercise to implement (some of) what `eval` implements?)

Finally, unless you have a class assignment that forbids it, I recommend using `match` instead of `car`, `cadr` etc.  With `match`, it's simply:

```
(define (my-eval x)
  (match x
    [(list lhs '* rhs) (* (my-eval lhs) (my-eval rhs))]
    [(list lhs '+ rhs) (+ (my-eval lhs) (my-eval rhs))]
    [(list) (list)]
    [_ x]))
```

You can also use quasi-quoting for the `match` patterns, which I usually find cleaner. The equivalent, that way:

```
(define (my-eval x)
  (match x
    [`(,lhs * ,rhs) (* (my-eval lhs) (my-eval rhs))]
    [`(,lhs + ,rhs) (+ (my-eval lhs) (my-eval rhs))]
    [`() `()]
    [_ x]))
```

Although some don't like the `` ` ``s and `,`s involved, I prefer those to all the `list`s.